# Rviz bug: transform from the same frame does not exist

Tags: kinect, rviz, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am getting a weird error from rviz when trying to show Laser Scan:

```
Transform [sender=/kinectFRMI] For frame [/openi_depth_frame]: Frame [/openi_depth_frame] does not exist
```

It is the same frame why needing a tf ?

I am trying to get fake laser scan from the point cloud /camera/rgb/points. And I wrote the node inspired from [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan).

The topic  /camera/rgb/points is publishing normally.

Thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11037/rviz-bug:-transform-from-the-same-frame-does-not-exist/) by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2011-08-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-08-27**:
Can you confirm that both your fixed frame and target frame are set to /openi_depth_frame (target frame could be set to fixed frame and it should work if the fixed frame is correct)? Also, double check for a misspelling since the default is openni_depth_frame if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this just a typo openni vs openi ?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) on 2011-08-29**:
Oups that really was a typo ! thank you everyone

**Comment by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) on 2011-08-28**:
I will verify monday, I hope it's just that ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it working, i.e. do you get a display, when you handtype your frame as fixed frame, and you just worry about the message?

The error message would be OK as there is no tf, but rviz should display the data in that case.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) on 2011-08-27**:
Hi, I get a display in rviz for the point cloud, from the kinect. And rostopic echo /scan show that there is data in this topic ... the problem is when I try to show /scan in rviz I get the error ! PS : in my laserScan I specified the frame at  /openi_depth_frame which exist in tf